# Why do I have differences making a Kaplan-Meier analysis using the same code and data?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am using the survival package in R studio with the following code to make a Kaplan-Meier-analysis:

```
surv_object <- Surv(time = cabos$sg, event = cabos$ï..status)
survfit(Surv(time = cabos$sg, event = cabos$ï..status) ~ 1, data = cabos)
fit1 <- survfit(surv_object ~loc , data = cabos) #p=0.97
ggsurvplot(fit1, data = cabos, pval = TRUE, risk.table = TRUE, risk.table.col = "strata",risk.table.y.text.col = T,risk.table.y.text = F, xlab= "Months", ylab= "Overall survival",legend.labs = c("C500", "C501", "C502", "C503","C504", "C505", "C508", "C509"), title = "Location")
```

This resulted in a Kaplan-Meier Curve with a p value of 0.97.

[image]

Yesterday, I added some labels so I could translate it to English, but the p value changed to 0.87.

[image]

There were no changes made to the code or the dataset. This concerned me so I ran the statistical analysis in SPSS and obtained the same result as my previous KM curve (p=0.97).

[image]

I have tried to run the analysis without the translation, without converting my variables to factors, converting my variables to factors, running new code from scratch but i can't get the previous value obtained.
What could be the problem with R studio?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for some pointers on improving your question to make it answerable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.